# Best way to identify manually selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing a chrome extension that allows user to click on some links. The extension should analyze the page (1 time per 1 hour, server-side) and if the link is changed - notify. The extension should work on any "normal" web page.

My chrome extension just allows to select element. All other job is done on server side.

What I tried:

- **ID** - the most obvious way, but a lot of web pages don't use ID for elements.
- **a tag** with exact **href**. But I also need some notifications for position changes. And there is a big chance that the extension will work not only with links.
- **e.path** - Should I keep it like html.child(0).child(2).child(1)... or identify them with their classes and types?

So, is there any good way to identify an element on some unknown page? How should I serialize the identifier?

I'm ok if it will not work after any major changes to html template.

Thank you :)

Comment: What about assigning randomly generated IDs to all the elements you want to check but don't have an ID?

Comment: This is more of a design problem than technical problem.

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about other people's webpages that he doesn't have control over.  It seems like he wants a way to identify specific regions of a webpage, in general.

Comment: Yes, it's about webpages that are not under my control

Comment: I don't know why people are down-voting this...

Comment: what is the links are button ? perhaps you need to go through all the child elements and add class "some_unique_name" then setup an observable

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but _"I'm doing a chrome extension"_ means he **has** control over the webpages.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to watch a set of webpages (linked from your extension) and determine if anything on the pages you're watching has changed?

Comment: "I'm doing a chrome extension" would usually mean you are working along websites indirectly, not directly.

Comment: Update: My chrome extension just allows to select element. All other job is done on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm reading your question right: You want to select some element on a webpage and have a server re-read that element on a timer loop to see if the element (text, for example) has changed.

Something like an ID would be easiest but, barring that, you might consider **XPath**, a standard for navigating through XML (or HTML) documents.

[W3Schools Reference on XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

**Just a note**: from a design perspective, this is going to be challenging because you don't have control over other pages. There's nothing stopping a website from changing IDs, reorganizing elements, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It looks like that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help! If it solves your problem, please consider upvoting or marking the answer as accepted :)